# keep 2 pictures open for a while in memory game in java

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, user-interface, jtogglebutton

hi there i am working on a project(card matching game) and it is almost finished but the things is when i clicked on second button to open the picture if it not same with first it suddenly closed. well nothings is wrong but user must see the picture for a while(maybe 2 second). so i used `Thread.sleep(2000)` but i doesnt work properly. it sets icon null and then start to wait 2 seconds. here is my code a tried to make a SSCCE,

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Menu;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JToggleButton;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class ConcentrationGame3 extends JFrame {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int buttoncounter=0;
    private int counter = 0;
    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel mainPanel;
    private JPanel buttonPanel;
    private JMenuBar menuBar;
    private JMenu menu;
    private JMenuItem menuItem;
    private int[] arr = new int[16];
    private int i,j;
    private int random;
    private int size = 4;
    private Icon hidden;
    private GameButton buttonFirst;
    private GameButton buttonSecond;
    int k=0;

    private Icon img[] = {UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.errorIcon"),
            UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.informationIcon"),
            UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.warningIcon")};

    private Icon iconList[] = new ImageIcon[size];

    public ConcentrationGame3(){

        createArray();
        initComponents();

    }


    private void initComponents(){


        frame = new JFrame("Concentration Game");

        menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        menu = new JMenu("Menu");

        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        menuBar.add(menu);

        menuItem = new JMenuItem("New Game");
        menu.add(menuItem);

        menuItem = new JMenuItem("Solve");
        menu.add(menuItem);

        menuItem = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        menu.add(menuItem);

        mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
        mainPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4,4,4,4));

        frame.setContentPane(mainPanel);

        buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4,4,5,5));
        buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.green);

        for(i=0; i<4; i++){

            final GameButton button = new GameButton(new JToggleButton(),iconList[i]);
            button.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){
                public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e){

                    button.setState();
                }
            });

            button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

                        try {
                            buttonActionPerformed(e,button);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                }
            });
            buttonPanel.add(button);
        }



        mainPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);


        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        //frame.pack();
        frame.setLocation(300, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    class GameButton extends JToggleButton{

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private JToggleButton gameButton;
        private Icon icon;

        public GameButton(JToggleButton gameButton,Icon icon){

            this.gameButton = gameButton;
            this.icon = icon;
        }

         public void setState() {
                if (this.isSelected() || !this.isEnabled()) {
                    this.setIcon(icon);
                } else {
                    this.setIcon(hidden);
                }
            }
        }

    private void buttonActionPerformed(ActionEvent e, GameButton button) throws InterruptedException {
        if(button.isSelected()){
            buttoncounter++;

            if(buttoncounter==1){
                buttonFirst = (GameButton) e.getSource();
            }
            else if(buttoncounter==2){
                buttonSecond = (GameButton) e.getSource();
                buttoncounter=0;

                    if( checkPairs(buttonFirst,buttonSecond) ) {
                        retirePair(buttonFirst,buttonSecond);
                    }

                    else{
                            Thread.sleep(2000);
                            buttonFirst.setIcon(hidden);
                            buttonFirst.setSelected(false);
                            buttonSecond.setIcon(hidden);
                            buttonSecond.setSelected(false);

                    }

            }
        }
    }

    private void retirePair(GameButton a, GameButton b){
        a.setSelected(true);
        a.setEnabled(false);
        b.setSelected(true);
        b.setEnabled(false);
    }

    private boolean checkPairs(GameButton first, GameButton second){

        if(first.getIcon().equals(second.getIcon()))
            return true;
        else
            return false;

    }

    private void createArray(){

        Random rnd = new Random();

        while(i<4){

            random = rnd.nextInt(3)+1;

            if(!includes(random)){
                arr[i]=random;
                iconList[i] = img[random-1];
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean includes(int rnd){

        counter=0;

        for(j=0; j<arr.length; j++){

            if(arr[j] == rnd){
                counter++;
                if(counter>1)
                    return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new ConcentrationGame3();

    }

}
```

i appreciated if you can help me. and thanks anyway :)

Comment: No, you didn't make it a SSCCE; you dumped all your code in the question and asked "What's wrong?"

Comment: It seems strange to me that your `GameButton extends JToggleButton` but also requires a `JToggleButton` to be constructed by its clients for the constructor -- and _stores_ a `JToggleButton` too. From what I recall of Java, `extends` is a "is-a" relationship, but you're using it as if it were a "has-a" relationship.

Comment: @Brian well yeah but this code has 100 lines more and pictures which i use specially on my computer. and i am not asking like "ok whats wrong give me the code please". read carefully...

Comment: I'm not sure why this is tagged with multithreading when there is only one thread.  Perhaps you ought to have multiple threads.

Comment: It is at least a smaller version of the whole -- I'll give credit (and 1+ for that), and allowed me to easily test a working solution before posting an answer.

Comment: @Keith yeap i just wrote thread and press enter it changed by itself and i couldnt fine onyl just "thread"

Comment: @quartaela, it's less about "regulations" and more about programming exactly what you _mean_: should your `GameButton` _derive_ from `JToggleButton` or should `GameButton` _include_ a `JToggleButton`? Your current code tries to do _both_, when it should do only _one_. Having code around that tries to do both is going to be a source of bugs, even if it isn't at all related to the bug that our esteemed Hovercraft has found. ;)

Comment: @sarnold ok i guess i fixed the problem with no sending `new JToggleButton()` i just send icon. is it true_?

Comment: @quartaela, that sounds much better!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't want to use Thread.sleep on the Swing thread, since as I'm sure you've read if you've done any searching, what this does is put ***Swing*** to sleep, sleep meaning all drawing is frozen, and all user interaction (like response to buttons) is frozen. Instead use a Swing Timer which will allow you to pause your application without preventing Swing from drawing your second image and showing both for 2 or 3 seconds.  The logic will be: show both images, start the timer, and when the timer "ticks" after 2 or 3 seconds (or whatever you set the delay to be), hide the images inside of the timer's ActionListener.

Also: make sure that you set the timer as non-repeating (there's a boolean method of Swing Timer that does this). Also, you'll want to make all of your JToggleButtons unresponsive (or enabled == false) while the  the two images are shown, and then you want the Timer to set all the non-paired buttons to a responsive state when it "ticks".

Comment: @quartaela: Have this link bookmarked: [The Really Big Index](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reallybigindex.html). Then search on that page for Swing Timers.