# How to add jlabel image hovering?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel, imageicon

How would I go upon adding `JLabel` hovering? Like when you move your mouse over top a `JLabel` a and new image will overlap it. I know how to make it work with buttons, but the same technique will not work for `JLabel`s. Will anyone guide me towards adding `JLabel` hovering? Please and thanks.

```
package src;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

/*
 * @Author - 0x29A
 * 
 * 
 */
public class Jframe {

    public static void main(final String args[]) {

        /*
         * @Images
         */
        final ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("Data/button.png");
        final JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);

        final ImageIcon icon1 = new ImageIcon("Data/button1.png");
        final JLabel label1 = new JLabel(icon1);

        final ImageIcon icon2 = new ImageIcon("Data/button2.png");
        final JLabel label2 = new JLabel(icon2);

        final ImageIcon icon3 = new ImageIcon("Data/button3.png");
        final JLabel label3 = new JLabel(icon3);

        final ImageIcon icon4 = new ImageIcon("Data/button4.png");
        final JLabel label4 = new JLabel(icon4);

        final ImageIcon icon5 = new ImageIcon("Data/button5.png");
        final JLabel label5 = new JLabel(icon5);

        final ImageIcon icon6 = new ImageIcon("Data/background.png");
        final JLabel label6 = new JLabel(icon6);

        /*
         * @Image Location
         */
        label.setBounds(282, 255, 96, 96);
        label1.setBounds(384, 255, 96, 96);
        label2.setBounds(282, 153, 96, 96);
        label3.setBounds(384, 153, 198, 96);
        label4.setBounds(181, 152, 96, 96);
        label5.setBounds(181, 255, 96, 96);
        label6.setBounds(0, 0, 765, 503);

        /*
         * @Frame
         */
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(765, 503));
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.add(label);
        frame.add(label1);
        frame.add(label2);
        frame.add(label3);
        frame.add(label4);
        frame.add(label5);
        frame.add(label6);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd start by learning how to use a MouseListener and MouseMotionListener, and [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) and [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mousemotionlistener.html) tutorial can help. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Thanks for those, but the problem is I have no idea how to use those with the code I have. Could you start me off by adding a mouse event for one of my label, and then I can follow how you did it and add the rest myself? That would be really thankful.

Comment: My philosophy is that you'll gain ***much*** more if you at least give it a go first yourself. Also, we'll be able to help you better by seeing what incorrect assumptions you may have. Finally, you've got nothing to lose by trying.

Comment: Hovercraft Full Of Eeels, thank you for the help as well :)

Answer (score 11):

Made a quick example, it uses a `MouseListener` and `MosueAdapter` to monitor `mouseExited()` and `mouseEntered()` events on the `JLabel`, and when either of these methods are called (i.e when the mouse is over the label or not) the picture is changed:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import javax.swing.*;

public class LabelHoverTest extends JFrame {

    Icon pic1;
    Icon pic2;
    JLabel label;

    public LabelHoverTest(String title) {
        super(title);
        pic1 = UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.informationIcon");
        pic2 = UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.questionIcon");
        createAndShowUI();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new LabelHoverTest("Label Hover Test").setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private void createAndShowUI() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        addComponentsToPane(getContentPane());
        setSize(300, 300);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void addComponentsToPane(Container contentPane) {
        label = new JLabel(pic1);

        contentPane.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        label.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                label.setIcon(pic2);
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                label.setIcon(pic1);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 example; `UIManager.getIcon`, shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7935040/230513), may be more self contained; `pack()`?

Comment: @trashgod beautiful, added it in to my answer :)

Answer (score 3):

you can use the `MouseEntered` mouse event for that and write this code
`JLabel.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("image location")));`

Comment: +1 only saw this after I posted my answer. Good suggestion :)