# Can you make a JFrame randomly choose a picture for it's background

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel, imageicon

Can you make a `JFrame` that just randomly chooses the provided three to four pictures as its background. So that when a user opens the `JFrame`, the `JFrame` will choose any of the stated pictures to choose from to be a background.

I want it something like this:

```
ImageIcon background = new ImageIcon("First Image.png");
JLabel label = new JLabel(background);
frame.add(label);
```

And the second picture:

```
ImageIcon background2 = new ImageIcon("Second Image.png");
JLabel label2 = new JLabel(background2);
frame.add(label2);
```

The third:

```
ImageIcon background3 = new ImageIcon("Third Image.png");
JLabel label3 = new JLabel(background3);
frame.add(label3);
```

And maybe the fourth:

```
ImageIcon background4 = new ImageIcon("Fourth Image.png");
JLabel label4 = new JLabel(background4);
frame.add(label4);
```

And I want some code so then the JFrame can use any one of these codes.

Also, is there a way to change the JFrame title randomly?

Like I want it something like:

`'My Game: It's the best!'`

...and then when the user opens the JFrame again, the title will change to, maybe:

`'My Game: Try it, it's new!'` and/or

`'My Game: You can play it easily!'` and/or

`'My Game: Find all the mysteries...'` and/or

`'My Game: Money don't go on trees!'` and other funny lines.

Hope I made it easy for you to understand!

Comment: Are you familiar with basic random number generation in java?

Comment: no, because i started learning java a few months ago. still a bit new to it. I know how to make `JFrame` and all that, but not good at making stuff that doesn't need `JComponents`. Like i don't know how to make a game menu screen like as if it's a picture with parts of it as a link to another action. I am only good at, well, let's say making a game menu with the use of `JButtons`, `JLabels`, etc. Sorry  for the long reply.

Answer (score 1):

Also consider [`Collections.shuffle()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29), illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3078354/230513) for `List<JLabel>` and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7935040/230513) for `List<Icon>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [java.util.Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class to generate random numbers.

If you want to select random string/image/image path you can just declare an array and get a random item from it. Here's an example code for titles:

```
//class level variable, supply your own lines.
final String[] TITLES = new String[]{"My Game: It's the best!", "My Game: Try it, it's new!"}

//next snippet is random title generation
//it's better to use only one random instance, 
//so you might want to declare this one on class level too
Random random = new Random(); 
int index = random.nextInt(TITLES.length); //get random index for given array.
String randomTitle = TITLES[index];
frame.setTitle(randomTitle);
```

You can do the same for image paths/images. Declare an array of type, get an object by random index:

```
final String[] IMAGE_PATHS = //initialization goes here

Random random = new Random(); 
String randomImagePath = IMAGE_PATHS[random.nextInt(IMAGE_PATHS.length)];
ImageIcon background = new ImageIcon(randomImagePath);
JLabel label = new JLabel(background);
```

Comment: aghh... doesn't matter. i don't really need to change the jframe title and background, as your way doesn't work, or the way I placed it doesn't work (i have a feeling it's the second option). but can you change the JFrame title font - maybe no? If you can't, then don't reply back. i'm not that great in java, mainly the integer part, because i followed a website that helps me to learn java [here](http://www.java-made-easy.com), and when i came to the integer part, it was boring, so i didn't really pay much attention on it. thanks

Comment: should be `String`, not `string`